# Pass argument with newline to external commands in vim

Tags: bash, shell, vim

When I'm interacting with the shell or writing a bash script I can do:

```
somecmd "some
arg"
```

Say now that I want to do the same in vim command-line mode:

```
:!somecmd "some<Enter>arg"
```

obviously won't work: as soon as I press `<Enter>` the command is executed. But neither the following do:

```
:!somecmd "some<C-V><Enter>arg"
:!somecmd "some<C-V>x0Aarg"
```

The first one inserts a carriage return instead of a line feed, which is right. The second one will break the command in two, trying to execute `somecmd "some<C-V>` first and then `arg"`, both of which fail miserably.

I guess I could work around this using some `echo -e` command substitution, or embedding `$'\n'`, but is it possible to type it directly in vim's command-line? I don't fully understand why the `"some<C-V>x0Aarg"` form doesn't work while `$'some\narg'` does. Is vim parsing the string previously to shell evaluation?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found the answer myself, but I'm leaving here for further reference anyway. The documentation of `:!` states:

> A newline character ends {cmd}, what follows is interpreted as a following ":" command. However, if there is a backslash before the newline it is removed and {cmd} continues. It doesn't matter how many backslashes are before the newline, only one is removed.

So you (I) should type `"some\<C-V>x0Aarg"` instead of `"some<C-V>x0Aarg"`.

Plus, I could have done it using the `system()` function instead of the `:!` command:

```
:call system("somecmd 'some<C-V>x0Aarg'")
```